# Windows no longer boots after unsuccessful Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot

I had win7 on my PC, I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10, installation was unsuccessful, I lost access to my windows 7, Ubuntu works only in recovery mode, my partitions are gone, and I can not go back to windows - does not boot, what should I do to get my computer back as it was? how to UN-install Ubuntu? is windows still on my computer? can I UN-install Ubuntu? would it help?

Comment: We can probably help if you want to fix your Ubuntu installation (if you tell us how "installation was unsuccessful"). If you want help with Windows, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: What option did you select during installation of Ubuntu? If you selected "use full disk", you will have overwritten the windows partition, and then it is completely and utterly GONE.

Answer (score 0):

instert Windows 7 installation disc.
GOTO recovery options and open command prompt and type these
`BootRec.exe /fixboot`
`BootRec.exe /fixmbr`
`BootRec.exe /RebuildBcd`